# Ignite RestartProcessFailureHandler failed to restart the stuck node

Tags: ignite

Ignite version v2.8.1-1

I have configured RestartProcessFailureHandler for handling the system critical errors like SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, however, when the error occurs, the restart never happens even after hours, is this expected behavior?

However, do see in the logs that indicating a restart has been requested but it seems never got executed.

As an alternative, I am thinking of enabling the rest API for a liveness check of the service and restarting the service once the check fails if the failure handler is not suitable for handling this case, please advise.

Thanks.

[2022-03-08T02:14:32,561][ERROR][disco-event-worker-#44%ignite-instance%][] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=RestartProcessFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=Unmod
ifiableSet []]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=sys-stripe-6, igniteInstanceName=ignite-instance, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1646705660633]]]
org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=sys-stripe-6, igniteInstanceName=ignite-instance, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1646705660633]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$3.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1810) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$3.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1805) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.worker.WorkersRegistry.onIdle(WorkersRegistry.java:234) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.onIdle(GridWorker.java:297) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryWorker.body(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2796) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120) [ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_312]
...

[2022-03-08T02:14:32,603][ERROR][node-restarter][] Restarting JVM on Ignite failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=sys-stripe-6, igniteInstanceName=ignite-instance, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1646705660633]]]
....

Comment: The Ignite server was running as a standalone service. The RestartProcessFailureHandler is configured to handle all errors, including the system errors, however, what we have observed that when the SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED occurs, the failure handler was not able to handle the restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way for a JVM to restart itself from Java application and therefore ignite rely on external tools to provide that capability. According to docs for `org.apache.ignite.failure.RestartProcessFailureHandler`
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/perf-and-troubleshooting/handling-exceptions#failures-handling
standard `ignite.sh|bat` scripts support restarting when JVM process exits with this code.

If you run ignite as part of your application, you can write your own script to start. And add `IGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=<path to marker file, which will be created by ignite during restart is called>` as jvm option at start java process. After this failure handler works, jvm exits with `org.apache.ignite.IgniteSystemProperties#IGNITE_RESTART_CODE`, then you need to check that `IGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE` was created, remove it and start jvm again.